# Sending image file to REST api using Ajax

Tags: javascript, phonegap, microsoft-custom-vision

I'm trying to work on Microsoft's Custom Vision API however they only have documentation for Python, Java, and .NET. [Based on their API instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vt61b.jpg) I have to include Precition-Key and Content-Type as part of the headers and "Set Body to : ". I'm using cordova to take the picture and once a photo is taken, it gives me a FILE_URI back.I've tried everything including using a Node server to do the request for me and while it works, it makes things slower so I wanted to do it through javascript only however I'm kind of stuck as of the moment.

```
        function takePhoto(){
            alert("WEW")
            let opts = {
                quality:80,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType:Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                mediaType:Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
                encodingType:Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                cameraDirection:Camera.Direction.BACK
            }
            navigator.camera.getPicture(pictureSuccess, pictureFailed, opts);
        }
        function pictureSuccess(imageUrl){
            alert(data);
              $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    data: imageUrl,      
                    headers: {
                     "Prediction-Key":"5d953acd19264d489ac0c15d590dd505",
                    "Content-Type":"application/octet-stream"
                    },               
                    url : 'https://southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/customvision/v2.0/Prediction/447f3fe7-05cd-46e3-9c8d-6460e3a3311c/image',                       
                    success: function(data){
                     alert(data)
                    },
                    error:function(e){
                        alert("Error"); 
                    }
                });



        }
```